# Protractor can't find by class value

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm trying to set up a simple Protractor test, but for some reason I'm getting the error:

> NoSuchElementerror: No element found using locator: By(css selector, btn-primary3)

This is the test I'm running,

```
describe('Login to **: ', function () {
    describe('When logging in with faulty data', function () {
        it('Should show an error toast', function () {
            browser.get('https://peter.dev.zen/#/inloggen');
            element(by.model('credentials.Gebruikersnaam')).sendKeys('JonSnow');
            element(by.model('credentials.Wachtwoord')).sendKeys('WinterIsComming');

            element(by.css('btn-primary3')).click();
        });
    });
});
```

This is the html from the browser,

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="text-input">
        <label for="username"> Gebruikersnaam </label>
        <input data-ng-model="credentials.Gebruikersnaam">
    </div>
    <div class="text-input>
        <label for="password"> Wachtwoord </label>
        <input data-ng-model="credentials.Wachtwoord">
     </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <a class="btn-primary3">Inloggen</a>
    </div>
< /fieldset>
```

Both the `by.model` work fine, but the

```
element(by.css('btn-primary3')).click();
```

Throws the error, but the class is right there in the browser. So what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Already found the answer through https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/basic/elements_spec.js

The problem is that if you do `by.css(body)` it searches for the body element. If you do `by.css(.body)` it searches for the element with the class name body.

```
it('should allow accessing subelements from within each', function() {
  browser.get('index.html#/form');
  var rows = element.all(by.css('.rowlike'));

  rows.each(function(row) {
    var input = row.element(by.css('.input'));
    expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('10');
  });

  rows.each(function(row) {
    var input = row.element(by.css('input'));
    expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('10');
  });
});
```